# How to delete index from url(PHP MVC)

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller, url-rewriting

I use my own php mvc My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The site's URLs are as follows:

```
test.com/blog/index/1
```

**number 1: ID is the column of the database**
How can I remove the Index from the MVC url

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way

```
RewriteEngine on

#in case of SSL
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt|assets/images/fav/favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```